# Button sound stops working after a while kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

The problem i have is that my button sound work but after a while stops working, this is my code .

```
fun ButtonClickes(v: View) {
    val buttonSound:MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click)
    val btnselected = v as Button
    var optionNumber = 0

    when (btnselected.id) {
        R.id.btn1 -> optionNumber = 1
        R.id.btn2 -> optionNumber = 2
        R.id.btn3 -> optionNumber = 3
        R.id.btn4 -> optionNumber = 4
        R.id.btn5 -> optionNumber = 5
        R.id.btn6 -> optionNumber = 6

    }

    buttonSound.start()
    action(optionNumber, btnselected)
}
```

Comment: please add your stack trace

Comment: i don't understand if you can explaine more plz

Comment: after a while means? it stops while playing or after 2 3 clicks it stops playing?

Comment: Afrer like 15 click sound not working any more

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help me https://stackoverflow.com/a/35644986/5697914

I use `SoundPool` instead of `MediaPlayer` and
you create instance of MediaPlayer after each click and this is why sounds stop working.